# C# native callback with pointer to struct parameter

Tags: c#, c, interop, pinvoke

I'm writing a C# wrapper for a native library. It contains this callback function:

```
typedef application_event_result(*application_event_ptr)(application_request* request);
```

The parameter is defined as such:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t    query;
  const char* client;
  bool        isAuthenticated;
  bool        isGuest;
} application_request;
```

I have defined the C# callback delegate like this:

```
  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public delegate application_event_result application_event([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        ref application_request request);
```

The structure in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct application_request
{
    public UInt32 query;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string client;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool isAuthenticated;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool isGuest; 
}
```

This all *seems* to work. The callback in C# is triggered, and the members of the struct have the expected values.

But upon return to native code, a heap corruption exception is triggered (0xc0000374).

Obviously, I would like to avoid that.

If I change the C# callback signature to use IntPtr instead of the "ref application_request" parameter, and then Marshal it manually using the following code it works.

```
var request = Marshal.PtrToStructure<application_request>(requestptr);
```

But I would like to have the signature be as precise as possible and not have to use the Marshaler myself.

Is there a away for me to change the callback delegate's signature so .net can convert the struct automatically?

Comment: The error is occurring due to the the size of the return parameter not being consistent. IntPtr is four bytes so you must declare in c# the return parameter as four bytes.  The location of the pointer also need to be in static memory space for both the c and C# code to work together. An IntPtr will work since it is in unmanaged static memory space.  A c# object is managed which will give an error if placed in unmanaged space.

Comment: The problem is not with the return value, but with the pointer-to-struct input parameter. Is there a way to mark that so it is put in unmanaged space?

Comment: @jdweng the return value looks like an enum no?

Comment: The return value is an enum. Sorry, that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `char*` member of the `struct`. The C# marshaler assumes that it is responsible for deallocating that memory. It does so by calling `CoTaskMemFree`. I think it is pretty clear that the memory is not meant to be destroyed by the C# code at all.

Marshal that member as `IntPtr` instead:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct application_request
{
    public UInt32 query;

    public IntPtr client;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool isAuthenticated;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool isGuest; 
}
```

Inside your callback method you can read the value of the string by calling `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

You wrap this up by making the members private and exposing them via properties. That will allow you to encapsulate the conversion from pointer to string.

Comment: Awesome, this works. And thanks for the good idea to wrap the IntPtr in a property which makes the conversion:
    public string Client => Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(client); 

I did not know that the struct properties could be private and the C# marshaler could still find them.